# Div's text left-bottom align CSS

Tags: css

could someone tell me how to align all those numbers to the left-bottom side? and in the middle to put something like an icon... That code will create 100 columns with numbers from 1-100, but I don't know how to align them in right place...
I have the current code:

```html
        <style>
        * {
            margin:0; padding:0; 
        }
            #board {
                width: 50%;
                font-size: 16px;
                margin: auto;
            }
            #row {
                display: flex;
                flex-wrap: nowrap;
              }
              
              #row > div {
                width: 100%;
                background-color: #f1f1f1;
                text-align: center;
                border: 1px solid gray;
                padding: 2%;
              }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="board">

        </div>
        <script>
            var board = document.getElementById("board");
            for(y=0;y<10;y++) {
            var row = document.createElement("div");
            row.setAttribute("id", 'row');
                for(x=0;x<10;x++) {
                var column = document.createElement("div");
                column.innerHTML = y*10+x+1;
                column.setAttribute("id", y*10+x+1)
                row.appendChild(column);
              }
              board.appendChild(row);
            }
        </script>
```

Comment: Why not use simple `table` with rows and columns, it's much easier to achieve what you want.

Comment: Also bear in mind you can't center an icon in the middle and align text t the bottom left at the same time. The text takes up space and so the icon would not be centered.

Comment: You could use CSS counters though - https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/zYoPdKa